# How to create a protected table in teradata?

Tags: teradata

i am using

```
create table xxx fallback,
                 before journal,
                 after journal,
                 checksum=default
(
    field1 integer,
    field2 integer 
)
primary index field1 ;
```

---

But i do not know if this is completely okay . i have some  questions :

1) can i use `before journal` and `after journal` at the same time ?

2) both `before journal` and `after journal` are used for backing up the table ? what is the difference ?

3) does `fallback` fully cover for both journals ?

4) is it important to have `checksum` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Of course you can do both before and after journal on a table. If you couldn't, the parser would complain about it :-)

2) *before journal* is used for *rollback* (undo log) and *after journal* for *rollforward* (redo log). So it might be a part of a backup solution.

3) *fallback* stores every row twice, including journal rows.

4) *checksum* is a disk I/O integrity check, i've hardly seen it used.

You might check the DDL and the Database Design manual for details.